# Custom icon for a button in Sencha Touch

Tags: button, icons, sencha-touch

In Sencha Touch if you want to give an icon to a button you must set the iconCls attribute of the button to the icon you want to give it. Sencha has a set of predefined icons, but I want to use other icons of which I have the png. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the png you need to define the icon not iconCls.

If you do have an SVG or Font it will be better scalable at no size cost. Try to find that icon on icomoon if possible to stay with fonts.